# package does not exist errors while building with bb ant tools

Tags: java, blackberry, ant

Im trying to automate our build process using bb ant tools and im running into a few errors

There are 3 different errors where 2 of them are related

[javac] D:\dev\java\workspaces\bb workspace\blackberry\Adaffix\src\com\adaffix\blackberry\AdaffixApplication.java:55: cannot find symbol     [javac] symbol: class PhoneListener     [javac] public class AdaffixApplication extends UiApplication implements PhoneListener, GlobalEventListener {

[javac] D:\dev\java\workspaces\bb workspace\blackberry\Adaffix\src\com\adaffix\blackberry\AdaffixApplication.java:29: package net.rim.blackberry.api.invoke does not exist     [javac] import net.rim.blackberry.api.invoke.Invoke;

[javac] D:\dev\java\workspaces\bb workspace\blackberry\Adaffix\src\com\adaffix\blackberry\main\block\AddBlock.java:167: warning: unmappable character for encoding UTF-8     [javac]   //tilf?j til db

and here is my build.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?> 
<project name="appname" default="build" basedir=".">

    <!-- BLACKBERRY ANT TOOLS --> 
    <property name="bb-ant-tools.home" location="D:/dev/bb-ant-tools-1.2.13-bin" /> 
    <taskdef resource="bb-ant-defs.xml" classpath="${bb-ant-tools.home}/bb-ant-tools.jar" />    
    <property name="jdehome" value="D:/dev/eclipse/blackberry/plugins/net.rim.ejde.componentpack6.0.0_6.0.0.43/components" />
    <property name="jdkhome" value="C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jdk1.6.0_34" />

    <!-- CONFIG STUFF  -->
    <property name="cod.name" value="appname" />
    <property name="app.name" value="appname" />
    <property name="app.version" value="2.7.5" /> 
    <property name="app.description" value="" /> 
    <property name="app.vendor" value="appname GmbH" /> 

    <!-- FOLDERS --> 
    <property name="build.dir" location="D:/dev/java/workspaces/bb workspace/blackberry/build" /> 
    <property name="bbminterface.dir" location="D:/dev/java/workspaces/bb workspace/blackberry/BBMInterface" /> 
    <property name="bbmimpl.dir" location="D:/dev/java/workspaces/bb workspace/blackberry/BBMImplementation" /> 
    <property name="main.dir" location="D:/dev/java/workspaces/bb workspace/blackberry/appname" /> 

    <target name="build" description="Builds Project">

        <!--<mkdir dir="${build.dir}" /> -->
        <javac target="1.4" source="1.4" destdir="${build.dir}" encoding="utf-8"> 
            <src path="${bbminterface.dir}/src"/> 
            <src path="${bbmimpl.dir}/src"/> 
            <src path="${main.dir}/src"/> 
            </javac>     


        <rapc output="BBMInterface" destdir="${build.dir}" jdehome="${jdehome}" jdkhome="${jdkhome}"  verbose="false" quiet="true" nowarn="true"> 
            <src> 
                <fileset dir="${bbminterface.dir}/src"/> 
            </src> 
            <jdp type="library" title="appname BBM Interface" vendor="${app.vendor}" version="1.0.0"> 
                <entry title="appname BBM Interface" description=""/>     
            </jdp> 
        </rapc> 
        <rapc output="BBMImplementation" destdir="${build.dir}" jdehome="${jdehome}" jdkhome="${jdkhome}" verbose="false" quiet="true" nowarn="true"> 
            <src> 
                <fileset dir="${bbmimpl.dir}/src"/> 
            </src> 
            <import location="${bbmimpl.dir}/external jars/bbm sdk/net_rim_bb_qm_platform.jar" /> 
            <import location="${build.dir}/BBMInterface.jar" /> 
            <jdp type="library" title="appname BBM Implementation" vendor="${app.vendor}" version="1.0.0" runonstartup="true" startuptier="6"> 
                <entry title="appname BBM Implementation" description="" runonstartup="true" startuptier="6"/>  
            </jdp> 
        </rapc> 

            <javac srcdir="${main.dir}" encoding="UTF-8" />
        <rapc output="${cod.name}" destdir="${build.dir}" jdehome="${jdehome}" jdkhome="${jdkhome}" verbose="false"> 

            <src> 
                <fileset dir="${main.dir}/src" /> 
            </src> 
            <src> 
                <fileset dir="${main.dir}/res" /> 
            </src> 
            <src>  
                <fileset file="${main.dir}/external jars/bb payment sdk/paymentapi.jar" /> 
                <fileset file="${main.dir}/external jars/bb advertising sdk/net_rim_bbapi_adv_app.jar" /> 
            </src> 
            <import location="${main.dir}/external jars/bb payment sdk/paymentapi.jar" /> 
            <import location="${main.dir}/external jars/bb advertising sdk/net_rim_bbapi_adv_app.jar" /> 
            <import location="${build.dir}/BBMInterface.jar"/> 

            <jdp type="cldc" title="${app.name}" vendor="${app.vendor}" icon="${main.dir}/res/image/icon.png" version="${app.version}" description="${app.description}" startuptier="7" ribbonposition="0"> 
                <entry title="${app.name}" icon="${main.dir}/res/image/icon.png" description="${app.description}" runonstartup="true" arguments="boot" systemmodule="true" startuptier="7" ribbonposition="0" /> 
                <!--<entry title="${app.name}" icon="../res/icon.png" description="@{description}" arguments="daemon" runonstartup="true" systemmodule="true" startuptier="7" ribbonposition="0" /> -->
            </jdp> 
        </rapc>
                <sigtool codfile="${build.dir}/BBMInterface.cod" password="password"/> 
                <sigtool codfile="${build.dir}/BBMImplementation.cod" password="password"/> 
                <sigtool codfile="${build.dir}/${cod.name}.cod" password="password" /> 
        </target> 
        <target name="sign" description="Sign the cod files"> 
        </target> 
    <!--<target name="clean"> 
        <delete dir="${dest.dir}" /> 
    </target> -->

</project>
```

can anyone point me in the right direction? im kind of lost here 
i thought that all the RIM api's would get included by bb ant tools automatically

Answer (score 1):

Are you building on Linux or Windows?   Rapc compiles java source to .class files with the Java SDK "javac" before compiling the class files into .cod files.  Unfortunately, rapc does not provide any way to pass the "-encoding" option to javac, so you are stuck with the platform default encoding.  This is cp-1252 on Windows, MacRoman on OSX, and UTF-8 on Linux.  Since it is trying to interpret your source as UTF-8, I'll guess you're using linux.

There are three options for fixing this:

1. You can go back to explicitly compiling the java source with the javac ant task.  Your previous attempt wasn't working because you were still passing source code to rapc.  Rapc can also start with class files, so you would do the javac step yourself, then pass the output directory to rapc for processing.
2. If you don't want to sort out the javac command yourself, you can also override the default system encoding, with a patch to bb-ant-tools.
3. If you only ever build your BlackBerry application on Linux, you can just switch your source file encoding to UTF-8 and be done with this.  This won't work well if any developers are using Windows though.  Windows is a common choice as it is the only place the simulators work.  By switching to UTF-8 encoding, the Windows developers will face the same problem you are facing now - rapc will be compiling with the system default of cp-1252, but the source files will be in UTF-8.

Comment: hello and thank you for answering!


it's a windows system that i am trying to do it on.

thank you for sorting out the javac section for me (doh..) i might revisit that if that is the only way to control the encoding fromt he build file

Comment: can you tell me more about overriding the system encoding with the patch?

Comment: i ended up changing the code so it didnt have the "illegal" characters. and now it seems to work!

Comment: @user991242 Glad you got it working. You should try to make sure your code editor and your build process agree on a character encoding. Since you use Windows, RIM's toolchain pretty much forces cp-1252. You should look into getting your editor to save your source files as cp-1252, and then you will spot these problems earlier.

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't in bb-ant-tools.

Why do you need `javac` part if your `rapc` could build project from sources? You even don't use result of `javac` after. My recommendation to remove it and it will fix your build.

Comment: thank you for replying!

but when i do that it still produces the same errors. 

this is the first time i try to do this so please forgive any hopelessly foolish mistakes! 

the reason i added the javac tags was because i wanted to add encoding and compliance level but as i understand from your answer i am doing it wrong..

Comment: Just remove comments with some utf symbol. Be careful you have two javac sections

Comment: thank you that fixed the does not exist errors! however now i some unicode errors:
         [rapc] D:\dev\java\workspaces\bb workspace\blackberry\Adaffix\src\com\adaffix\util\string\StringUtil.java:449: illegal character: \177
         [rapc]   if(c == 'a' || c == 'u' || c == 'o' || c == 'Ä±') {
which was why i tried to add the javac statement in the first place

Comment: find unicode table of symbols and replace it with \uxxxx. it will fix compilation

Comment: @EugenMartynov I agree, '\uxxxx' is a good workaround for now.  It would be better to make sure the code editor agrees with the tools on the character encoding in use, otherwise these problems will be neverending.  A compilation error is the best result.  The worst would be matching against the wrong character, or having the wrong text appear.

Answer (score 0):

happened to me. was because i hadn't copied selenium-server-standalone-3.4.0.jar to my C:\jars dir (ws.jars)